# ImportError: No module named 'tweepy.auth'

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to make a twitter bot using python and twitter but was getting an error. I fixed the first error with this solution but now I have another and at this point I am not sure what to do ( [Error with tweepy OAuthHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075001/error-with-tweepy-oauthhandler))

```
import tweepy
import sys

from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler

argfile = str(sys.argv[1])

CONSUMER_KEY = 'aaa'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'bbb'
ACCESS_KEY = 'ccc'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'ddd'
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
```

Comment: pip install tweepy

Comment: i assume he already installed it since the first import tweepy line did not return an error

Comment: Just in case, what's the name of your `.py` file? Make sure it is not also named `tweepy.py`

Answer (score 1):

try removing that `.auth` from the module import portion, and get `OAuthHandler` directly from `tweepy`.
Also check your tweepy module if it contains auth scrpit

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @davedwards in the comments. My file was also saved as Tweepy.py. Renaming it solved the problem.

Comment: lol same here, can't believe this

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I tried to remove .auth but it didn't work.

My problem was the duplicated file of tweepy if you use 
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install

make sure to extract tweepy folder that exists inside tweepy. And remove the main tweepy file and try again. It worked for me